# Vue Warning on Console : You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm a new student of Computer Science and I have a school project to do on Vue.js.
It is working, but it shows the following Warning:

**[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.**

English is not my first language, so I'm sorry if I write anything wrong in advance, but I'll try to explain what I have to do on the project.

I have to create a Photo Grid/Album that shows no more than 3 photos on each line. Something like this:
[Example of how it has to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvXMD.png)

The code is like this:

```
  <template>
<v-container>
  <!-- 'v-container' est´substituindo ' div class="clubes-lista" '-->
  <div class="grid-photo">
    <v-container class="grey lighten-3">
      <v-row
        v-for="index in numberLines()"
        :key="index"
        class="grey lighten-3"
      >
        <v-col v-for="n in 3" :key="n" cols="4">
          <v-card v-if="numberPhotos > checkInsertedAllPhotos()" outlined>
            <v-img
              src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/96/28/b7/9628b7892fd0543782f53eeec4bae502.jpg"
              alt="Bird Photo"
            >
            </v-img>
            <div class="photo-subtitle">
              <v-icon size="15">mdi-heart-outline</v-icon>
              <p>The Cockatiel</p>
            </div>
          </v-card>
          <v-card v-else></v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</v-container>
```

```
<script>
export default {
name: "PhotoGrid",

data() {
  return {
    listPhotosOnGrid: [],
    numberPhotos: 0,
    numberTotalLines: 0,
    countPhotos: 0,
  };
},

computed: {},

methods: {
  createPhotosList() {
    var listPhotos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var aux = {
        id: i + 1,
        src:
          "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/96/28/b7/9628b7892fd0543782f53eeec4bae502.jpg",
        subtitle: "The cockatiel",
      };

      listPhotos.push(aux);
    }

    this.listPhotosOnGrid = listPhotos;
    this.numberPhotos = listPhotos.length;
  },

  numberLines() {
    this.createPhotosList();
    var photosMultipleThree = this.numberPhotos;

    while (photosMultipleThree % 3 != 0) {
      photosMultipleThree = photosMultipleThree + 1;
    }
    this.numberTotalLines = photosMultipleThree / 3;

    return photosMultipleThree / 3;
  },

  checkInsertedAllPhotos() {
    var cont = this.countPhotos++;
    return cont;
  },
},
```

};

```
<style scoped>
.photo-subtitle {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.photo-subtitle p {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

So... Trying to figure out what is happening, I think the Warning comes from the following line:

```
<v-card v-if="numberPhotos > checkInsertedAllPhotos()" outlined>
```

The **if** is because it can't show more images that what is given. For example, each line shows 3 photos, so if I don't have a total of photos that is multiple os 3, I don't want to fill all columns on the last line, only the necessary to show all the photos.

But I just think, based on some tests, I'm not sure if the Warning comes from this line.

The code works, but I feel something is not right. (***It works partialy actually, because I still don't know how to get the info from the array to show, so it only loops the same thing***)

I want to learn how to make it right.

So does anyone can tell me what I can do to make the Warning disappear or if I have to change everything, and make make a new logic for it to work properly.

I just want to learn.

Thank you so, so much and sorry again if this is a stupid question, or if I'm making everything wrong, hehe.
And sorry if I wrote anything wrong.

:)

Comment: First of all, 
1. this function `checkInsertedAllPhotos()` always return 1 because you only increment 1 once.
2. `v-for="index in numberLines()"` The numberLines() here is a number, because you return photosMultipleThree / 3. You can't loop through a number.

Comment: 3. It's not recommended to use v-if inside v-for. Instead, using computed properties to filtered the array first, then loop through the filtered array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look to your code. First I would recommend you **to stop using the `var`** keyword but use `let` or `const` instead (you may check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) and have a look at the scope based on those keyword, the `var` scope is very unusual nowadays and it will lead you to some issues).

Regarding your particular issue of infinite update loop, the problem comes from your `checkInsertedAllPhotos` function. I would explain it like this :

- In the v-if Vue internal mechanisms checks if the element should be rendered by triggering the function `checkInsertedAllPhotos`
- When executing the function `checkInsertedAllPhotos` the data `countPhotos` is increased (by the way it would be better to just do

  `this.countPhotos ++; return this.countPhotos;`
- Since the Data has been modified Vue is triggering a re-render of the page
- Since there is a re-render Vue checks in the v-if if the element should be rendered by triggering the function `checkInsertedAllPhotos`.

And it could be infinite if Vue doesn't prevent it !

I would suggest to re-work a little bit your logic indeed. However a quick solution for your problem would be that when you're checking an index in your list : for example if you want to display `listPhotosOnGrid[i]`, you check if `i<numberPhotos` with a v-if and in the v-else you can display something else if you want.

I also think you could have a much simpler code, by leveraging css (for example css-grid). You can have something as simple as this :

```
<div v-for="n in 100">
    <img v-bind:src="`https://i.pinimg.com/photos/${n}.png`">
</div>
```

and some css to style it and only have 3 items per rows. If you want to learn about css-grid I would recommend [Mozzila documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or the [following tutoriel](https://cssgridgarden.com/).

Right now I have a little trouble understanding the exact question, since there are multiples topics inside to solve but I hope my explanation on the infinite loop will help you !

Have fun while learning Vue !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who helped me, and you sure helped me!!!!

I'm sorry I could only anwser today.
I think I was able to do much better on the code, I changed it a lot, specially the logic on the code. And I think it can get even better, but for sure I already made a big progress, hehe.

I was a bit reluctant of posting this question because even though that as the time that I posted it I wasn't sure of what to do, I kinda of had the feeling that was something stupid (like a stuid question), and that I would only be taking the time of anyone who stopped by my question. But I only got amazing answers, with everyone being so patient, so THANK YOU SO, SO MUCH!!

(I'm also new to StackOverflow, so I hope I'm making everything right, hehe)